# How to display an image in the terminal without a display / window manager?

Tags: linux, image, terminal, debian, raspberry-pi3

I am a relatively new user to Linux and finally got my hands on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B rev 1.2. I have Debian Bullseye installed on it. Just the terminal version, because I am mainly using it over my Wi-Fi network by SSHing into it.

**The system details are below:**

```
pi@raspberrypi:/media/ecvol $ neofetch
       _,met$$$$$gg.          pi@raspberrypi 
    ,g$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$P.       -------------- 
  ,g$$P"     """Y$$.".        OS: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) aarch64 
 ,$$P'              `$$$.     Host: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2 
',$$P       ,ggs.     `$$b:   Kernel: 5.15.74-v8+ 
`d$$'     ,$P"'   .    $$$    Uptime: 43 mins 
 $$P      d$'     ,    $$P    Packages: 627 (dpkg) 
 $$:      $$.   -    ,d$$'    Shell: bash 5.1.4 
 $$;      Y$b._   _,d$P'      Terminal: /dev/pts/0 
 Y$$.    `.`"Y$$$$P"'         CPU: BCM2835 (4) @ 1.200GHz 
 `$$b      "-.__              Memory: 86MiB / 909MiB 
  `Y$$
   `Y$$.                                              
     `$$b.                                            
       `Y$$b.
          `"Y$b._
              `"""
```

I am trying to view an image in the terminal using feh, but it throws up this error,

```
pi@raspberrypi:/media/ecvol $ feh jas.jpg
feh ERROR: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?
```

I think this has to do with the Pi not having any kind of display manager? I have a very vague idea. Is it possible to view an image without installing a Window Manager or Desktop Environment. If yes then what should I? If no, then what should I install to do this.

I tried using feh and multiple google searches

Comment: Where do you want to see an image? In SSH terminal? In your host X server? Latter can be done with SSH X11 forwarding feature.

Comment: In the SSH terminal, is it possible? What is the error trying to say?

Comment: SSH terminal is text terminal, it is incapable to display images. The error says that X client (feh) can't find X server to connect to.